# Extract particular file from Zip archive in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Ruby Project. I need to extract a particular file from Zip Archive instead of all files. I tried the following code by using "zip" gem:-

```js
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'
@folder = "C:/Users/Shek/Desktop/aadi_elements.zip"
@zip = ''
@vals = []
@files_names = []
@articles = Article.all
Zip::File.open(@folder) { |zip_file|
  @zip = zip_file
  zip_file.each { |f|
    @vals.push f
    @files_names.push f.name
  }
}
```

Above code extract all files but my reqiurement is to extract particular file on which a click event is performed.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not just put a simple if (f.name == <file name that was clicked>) into the zip_file.each ?

Comment: @xyious Yes this condition works nicely but the thing is on click of a file name i have to call another method in which I have to zipped file. Then each loop would be executing for number of files which aren't required. Thus the code will not be optimized

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about optimizing until it proves to be a problem. also obviously you can break to stop the loop after you find the right file as a slight optimization. you could probably even skip to the number of the file if they're sorted the same in the decompress function and the website's display function. Would be worth testing if that's true.

Comment: Thanks @xyious for the response :). I implemented it using bash scripting via controller and it worked great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether or not use of the gem is required, so I'll suggest that the easiest thing might be to call out to the `unzip` OS executable. Here's a couple of lines of shell commands that illustrate the use of `unzip myzipfilespec desired_file_to_unzip`.

First we create a zip containing (empty) files a, b, and c, and show the content of the zip file with `unzip -v`.  Then we unzip a single file from the zip file using `unzip`.

```
➜  ~   touch a; touch b; touch c; zip abc a b c; rm a b c; unzip -v abc
updating: a (stored 0%)
updating: b (stored 0%)
updating: c (stored 0%)
Archive:  abc.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Ratio   Date   Time   CRC-32    Name
--------  ------  ------- -----   ----   ----   ------    ----
       0  Stored        0   0%  06-06-16 17:51  00000000  a
       0  Stored        0   0%  06-06-16 17:51  00000000  b
       0  Stored        0   0%  06-06-16 17:51  00000000  c
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       0                0   0%                            3 files
➜  ~   unzip abc b
Archive:  abc.zip
 extracting: b
```

Comment: Not familiar with bash scripting :(

Comment: The first (composite command) line was just to set up a zip file for illustration purpose.  All you really need to know is that, assuming the `unzip` utility is present, you can simply do: `unzip #{zip_filespec} #{filespec_to_unzip}` to unzip the desired file.

Comment: I recommend creating a temporary directory and playing around with `zip` and `unzip` on the command line with dummy files.  These utilities are extremely handy.  `unzip -v` shows the contents of a zip file, this is like the `puts` of zip file management. ;)

Comment: ah really great solution. It worked fantastically. Thankyou very muchhh for saving lots of my time :)